# Axis2 (war) + Tomcat 6: WSDL2Java missing?

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, apache-axis, wsdl2java

I am trying to learn how to implement Web Services using Axis2 and Tomcat, but i'm afraid that i'm not grasping some of the basics.

I was following this [tutorial](http://wso2.org/node/95) but when i attempted to use WSDL2Java i noticed that i do not have the tool anywhere. This happens due to the fact that i downloaded and installed the .war (web archive) version of Axis2, right?

How can i incorporate the tool on the current installation inside Tomcat? Will a copy/paste suffice?

Thanks in advance,
Hal

Comment: wsdl2java is a command line tool. Download axis2 'Standard Binary Distribution', then you can use it easily from the default directory layout.

Comment: Thank you! I've downloaded and attempted to run it again, but got another issue: it says that the AXIS_HOME variable is not set (which it is, actually, to C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\axis2\). 

Any ideas? Tried to force SET AXIS_HOME=(...) by command line but won't work either

Comment: As I understand you are running on Windows, so you have to add Environment Variable AXIS_HOME (Control Panel->System->Environment Variables). Restart you cmd window once you are done.

Comment: Yup, Windows Server 2008. The variable is (and was) set up correctly in the Environment Variables windows.... wtf. Tried both local user and global, still won't work even after rebooting the pc :S

Comment: Echo %AXIS2_HOME% returns " C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\axis2"

Comment: Fixed it. The variable had to be set to the binary distro. path, not the .war one. This is silly, what good is the .war for anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gennady Shumakher said, the utility resided in the Standard Binary distro only.
Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

If u have sucessfully installed tomcat and if it is up and running all u need is copy the axis2.war under /webapps  and restart for confirmation (on some Os Tomcat has problems )

and directly call http://localhost:8080/axis2

u should b e able to view the Axis screen ...

the axis2.war file is avaliable in this url

> http://www.carfab.com/apachesoftware//axis/axis2/java/core/1.6.0/axis2-1.6.0-war.zip

and if u want to use "WSDL2Java"  then download this

http://www.carfab.com/apachesoftware//axis/axis2/java/core/1.6.0/axis2-1.6.0-bin.zip

and set the classpath /path  after exploding te zip in any folder  "c:/temp/axis2"

u will find wsdl2... in the bin folder

with regards
karthik